# Kafka records-lag-max variation vs records-consumed-rate

Tags: apache-kafka

Regarding Apache Kafka, would it make sense for the records-lag-max metric variation equal the records-consumed-rate metric, when we only have a single consumer of the topic?

Answer (score 2):

Answer is no.
Frome doc, `records-lag-max` describes

> The maximum lag in terms of number of records for any partition in this window

It is a maximum value.

`records-consumed-rate` describes

> The average number of records consumed per second